# What's the difference between the nls-function and the power least squares function?

Tags: r, least-squares, nls

I want to know what the exact difference is between the R-function nls and the least squares method. I thought it was the same, but it gives different outcomes, see the example below. I want to find a power function for data (x,y).
I searched the sourcecode of the function nls, but I can't find the difference. Can anyone help me?

> x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
>
> y <- c(4,7,2,34,25,53,57,77,87,99)
>
> data_xy <- data.frame(x,y)
>
> function_nls <- nls(y ~ a*x^b, data=data_xy, start=c(a=5, b=3))
>
> n <- length(x)
>
> i <- seq(1,n,1)
>
> b <- (n * sum(log(x[i])*log(y[i])) - sum(log(x[i])) * sum(log(y[i]))) / (n * sum(log(x[i])^2) - (sum(log(x[i]))^2))
>
> a <- exp((sum(log(y[i])) - b * sum(log(x[i]))) / n)
>
> cat(sprintf('P = %f * V ^ %f \n', a,b))

P = 2.075821 * V ^ 1.647545

> coef(function_nls)

```
   a        b
```

2.618066 1.593658

Comment: NLS is Nonlinear Least Squares while PLS is Power Least Squares, the difference is already in the name, Nonlinear =/= Power.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @user2974951 but if I put a power function in the nls-function it will calculate PLS, right?

Comment: I don't see any arguments for this in the nls function.

Comment: @user2974951 the first argument of the nls function is a formula. If I type here a power function (a*x^b), than it is PLS right?

Comment: No, it's still nonlinear least squares. You have to be careful with the notation, any transformations of variables should be surrounded by `I()`, that is `I(x^power)`. Have a look at http://www.css.cornell.edu/faculty/dgr2/teach/R/R_CurveFit.pdf